# call outer class without using the variable in main file

Tags: python

I had meet the problem that, when calling method in class A, I need to set the value or call some functions in other classes, but I need all of them in the same python file, which is really long and ugly
. Are there some appropriate ways to write it **clean**?

Ideally, I hope this classes can be in seperate python file.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.value = 10

    def set(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value
        # set B value = new_value * 2
        c.b.set(new_value * 2)
        # set C value = new_value / 2
        c.value = new_value / 2


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.value = 10

    def set(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        self.value = 1
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
    # class a function is called then class B and class C do somethings ...
    c.a.set(100)
    print(c.value)
    print(c.a.value)
    print(c.b.value)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it sounds like somehow you're unaware of the `import` statement?

Comment: All this looks like a bad design to me. In `A.set`, you rely on the variable `c`, which is defined globally in your set-up code. I know this is a toy example, but what sort of coupling are you looking to achieve? Do A and C need to be so tightly coupled? You could perhaps pass an instance of C to the A member on C, and have A update C whenever A.set() is called.

Comment: You mean import variable/instance of class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to your design constraints, but here is one where dependencies are eliminated:

```
# imagine each of these classes are in their own projects (/A,/B,/C), in their own files (A.py, B.py, C.py)
class A:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.value = 10
        self.c = c

    def set(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value
        # set B value = new_value * 2
        self.c.b.set(new_value * 2)
        # set C value = new_value / 2
        self.c.value = new_value / 2

# class B as before

class C:
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.value = 1
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()

# Now main.py
from A.A import A
from B.B import B
from C.C import C
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C(A, B)   # Pass in the classes A and B which C will instantiate
    # class a function is called then class B and class C do somethings ...
    c.a.set(100)
    print(c.value)
    print(c.a.value)
    print(c.b.value)
```

btw: A class which does not derive from another does not need to call super init.